# Reading words from the keyboard and puting them in a Matrix

Tags: c

I have to read 5 words from the keyboard and put them in a matrix. For example if I have the word RED, the letters will be split between the columns of the first row.  R  E  D and so on.

This is my code but it exits after I scanf 5 letters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
char mat[3][3];

for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &mat[i][j]);
    }

for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        printf("%s\t",mat[i][j]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then `scanf` won't work. Use `fgetc`. And HORSE has 5 letters where your matrix only has 3 columns.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the user must enter words using the keyboard, not an external file

Comment: How about `fgetc(stdin)`?

Comment: And read the `scanf` documentation about the format specification because your `scanf("%s", &mat[i][j]);` has a big error causing your program to abort. Some compilers will warn you about your error, so turn warnings of your compiler on.

Comment: There are many, many layers of abstraction between "the keyboard" and your program.  You do *not* want to read from the keyboard.  You want to read from stdin, and you need to stop thinking about stdin as "the keyboard".

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified any size for the strings... I will presume they are of *arbitrary length*...

```
// Takes input using the 'stdin' stream...
char* read_input(void)
{
    char ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t size = len + 2;
    char* str = realloc(NULL, size);
    if (!str)
        return str;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != -1 && ch != '\n')
    {
        str[len++] = ch;
        if (len == size)
        {
            str = realloc(str, size += 2);
            if (!str)
                return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++] = '\0';
    return realloc(str, len);
}
```

This function will read the input, now we also need a function for checking if the string is a valid **word**... i.e, it contains only *alphabets*...

```
// Checks whether the specified string is alphabetic or not...
int is_alpha_string(char* str, char* err_msg)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (!isalpha(str[i]))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, err_msg);
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

*After this, just do:*

```
// The 'main()' function...
int main(void)
{
    char* matrix[5];
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < 5u; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your word here: ");
        matrix[i] = read_input();
        i -= !is_alpha_string(matrix[i], "Error! Entered text is not a valid word!\n\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s\n", matrix[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** *And **don't forget** to add these includes at the top:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: `str = realloc(str, size += 2);` will leak the mem `str` pointed to before if `realloc()` fails. Also, `return realloc(str, len);` is a no-no.